# Retrofit error-Missing either @GET URL or @Url parameter

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am working on Youtube API.
The base URL is `<https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search/>`

Request :GET

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q={search_keyword}&key={API_KEY}
```

ApiService Interface code-

```
public interface ApiService {
    @GET("")
    Call<YoutubeResponse> searchVideos(@Query("part") String part,
                                   @Query("q") String q,@Query("key") String apiKey);
}
```

The error: **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing either @GET URL or @Url parameter.**
in the line of code

```
Call<YoutubeResponse> call=service.searchVideos("snippet",s, URLConstants.Youtube_API_KEY);
```

I'm a beginner. Please help!

Answer (score 232, accepted):

It's much more semantically correct to use  https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/ as your base URL and then declare `@GET("search/")` on your service method.

That said, if you *really* want your base URL to be the full path you can use `@GET(".")` to declare that your final URL is the same as your base URL.

Comment: I loved that "."

Comment: Although it's definitely more satisfying to declare the path in the call, there are cases where a whole path changes between environments, and it makes sense to declare it in the base url.

Comment: wow! my URL is http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=star war .its worked thanks

Comment: Why to add the "." instead of adding nothing?? Seems confusing