# Why my get String http in retrofit don't work?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have a link and an API:

```
@GET("users/{username}")
Call<String> getStringResponse(@Path("username") String username);
```

---

```
public class APIClientDetail {

public Retrofit getRetrofit(String baseUrl) {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            // add other factories here, if needed.
            .build();

        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

I call:

```
APIClientDetail apiClientDetail= new APIClientDetail();
    Retrofit retrofit= apiClientDetail.getRetrofit("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=");

    GitHubService scalarService = retrofit.create(GitHubService.class);
    Call<String> stringCall = scalarService.getStringResponse("EMyW7WvhEso");
    stringCall.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                String responseString = response.body();
                // todo: do something with the response string
                modelInterface.dataSuccessful();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
            modelInterface.dataError();
        }
    });
```

But it don't work, not into the function `onResponse`.

Comment: does it go to `onFailure` ?! can you print the `t.getMessage()` in onFailure and add it to your question here to see have more clue on whats happening ?

Comment: before checking if condition , just put a log and see what response you are getting

Comment: when i use link: gateway.fpts.com.vn/g5g/fpts/?s=realtime_index_ho
---------------- 
baseUrl: gateway.fpts.com.vn/g5g/fpts 
----------------------
@GET("") Call<String> getStringResponse(@Query("s") String name); It don't work!

Answer (score 1):

```
@GET("users/{username}")
```

If your base url is `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=`, then the url being created by retrofit for the method `getStringResponse()` is `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=users/EMyW7WvhEso`.

Your base url should be `https://www.youtube.com/` and define your api like the following:

```
@GET("watch")
Call<String> getVideo(@Query("v") String videoID);
```

Comment: Thank you! It's good work. But when i use link: http://gateway.fpts.com.vn/g5g/fpts/?s=realtime_index_ho

baseUrl: http://gateway.fpts.com.vn/g5g/fpts/

 @GET("")
    Call<String> getStringResponse(@Query("s") String name);

It don't work!

Comment: add a slash at the end of the baseurl

Comment: I did add but it don't work! :(
Retrofit retrofit= apiClientDetail.getRetrofit("http://gateway.fpts.com.vn/g5g/fpts/");
It error: "Missing either GET URL or Url parameter."

Comment: @TrangĐỗ check out this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/40062661/2235972   Basically use `@GET(".")` if you want to keep it empty