# Retrofit response body gives null

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit2

I'm trying to use an API that returns JSON, and I'm using Retrofit to get the response and parse it

the API retruns JSON like the following :

```
{
 "total": 1244881,
 "totalHits": 500,
 "hits": [
  {
   "id": 5205518,
   "pageURL": "https://pixabay.com/photos/landscape-sea-sky-clouds-sunset-5205518/",
   "type": "photo",
   "tags": "landscape, sea, sky",
   "previewURL": "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/05/22/14/04/landscape-5205518_150.jpg",
   "webformatWidth": 640,
   "webformatHeight": 427,
    ...
    ...
  },
    ...
    ...
  ]
}
```

And for The GSON to convert this json into an Object I created two classes : 
the first is : `RquestModel.java`

```
public class RequestModel {

    @SerializedName("total")
    private long total;

    @SerializedName("totalHits")
    private long totalHits;

    @SerializedName("hits")
    private List<Image> hits;

    //Getters and setters down here...

}
```

and the second class for the array in the json is :

```
public class Image {

    @SerializedName("id")
    private long id;

    @SerializedName("pageURL")
    private String pageURL;

    @SerializedName("type")
    private String type;

    @SerializedName("tags")
    private String tags;

    @SerializedName("previewURL")
    private String previewURL;

    @SerializedName("previewWidth")
    private long previewWidth;

    @SerializedName("previewHeight")
    private long previewHeight;

    @SerializedName("webformatURL")
    private String webformatURL;

    @SerializedName("webformatWidth")
    private long webformatWidth;

    @SerializedName("webformatHeight")
    private long webformatHeight;

    @SerializedName("largeImageURL")
    private String largeImageURL;

    @SerializedName("imageWidth")
    private long imageWidth;

    @SerializedName("imageHeight")
    private long imageHeight;

    @SerializedName("imageSize")
    private long imageSize;

    @SerializedName("views")
    private long views;

    @SerializedName("downloads")
    private long downloads;

    @SerializedName("favorites")
    private long favorites;

    @SerializedName("likes")
    private long likes;

    @SerializedName("comments")
    private long comments;

    @SerializedName("user_id")
    private long userId;

    @SerializedName("user")
    private String user;

    @SerializedName("userImageURL")
    private String userImageURL;


    //Getters and Setters down here ..... 



}
```

And for the interface that the GSON converter uses is like this :

```
public interface ImageAPIService {

    @GET(".")
    public Call<RequestModel> getRequest();

}
```

and When I try to use the response from the Callback like this :

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                            .baseUrl(API_URL)
                            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                            .build();

ImageAPIService api = retrofit.create(ImageAPIService.class);

Call<RequestModel> request = api.getRequest();

request.enqueue(new Callback<RequestModel>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<RequestModel> call, Response<RequestModel> response) {
        mViewModel.setTxt(response.body().getTotal() + "");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<RequestModel> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});
```

that gives an Exception of type: `java.lang.NullPointerException` :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long com.mapps.pixabayclient.models.RequestModel.getTotal()' on a null object reference
```

I tried to debug it and everything seems fine to me, I don't know what I have missed. if someone could notice the mistake, I'd be very thankful.

And thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: check if `response.isSuccessful()` first and log the results to see what's wrong. Also log the http response code to understand what's going on

Comment: Inside on response set `RequestModel req = response.body();` And then try to get `req.getTotal()`

Comment: @sonnet, it's strange, it gives 400 error code and I don't know why
I updated the post and put the interface that the GSON Converter uses to see of there's a mistake at that level.

Comment: this is potentially problematic `@GET(".")`. Can you post your url? Doesn't have to exact. example: `https://example.com/api/hits` or something

Comment: @sonnet here's the API URL 
https://pixabay.com/api/?key=xxxxxxxx

Comment: Please remove the comment with real api keys. Don't post your api keys publicly

Comment: @sonnet  it's done!.

Comment: What is your API_URL string? Is it the same url with api key as the one you commented?

Comment: @sonnet yes it is, with the xxxxx is the key. 
https://pixabay.com/api/?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx and with https at the beginning, for some reason it is removed here.

Comment: It would be nice if you delete the whole `hits` array from the json and relevant code from the model class. It would reduce the question size and future readers won't have to read a lot because they are quite irrelevant to the problem as we discovered.

Comment: @sonnet, Ok I go that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem as you already figured out is that with your setup, the key is getting removed from the request. This is the response when I make the request with your setup.

> Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=400, message=Bad Request, url=https://pixabay.com/api/}

But it shouldn't be the case. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40062661/2235972) from Jake Wharton, if we use `@GET(".")`, then the whole base_url becomes the request url. For some reason, that isn't the case for you. [Maybe if we log the request url using some interceptor then we can understand better what's going on (whether it's a retrofit issue or a backend issue)].

Anyways, one solution is to pass the api key for each request like the following:

```java
@GET(".")
public Call<RequestModel> getRequest(@Query("key") String key);
```

and call the function like this:

```java
api.getRequest("my_api_key")
```

Another solution is to hard-code the api key into `@GET("api/?key=xxxxx")` like you already did.

The better solution is to [use okhttp interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32948083/is-there-a-way-to-add-query-parameter-to-every-request-with-retrofit-2) to intercept the requests and add the api key query parameter in the url. With this solution, you won't have to pass the api key for each function call.

Comment: Thanks mate for helping
it is really strange that the code I made first didn't work for some reason, I'll look into it and make a follow up in this post for me detailed debugging.
Thanks anyway, you helped a lot !.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the `@GET` annotation, as I moved the api/?key inside the parenthesis of the GET annotation -> `@GET("api/?key=xxxxxxx")`
but the problem now is that I should pass the key in every GET or any other request type.

is there a workaround to systematically pass the key in each request ?

Comment: Good on you for finding the problem. I was also debugging the issue and was preparing a more detailed answer